# VS2019 - Durable function (v1.8.3) and non-durable Function in a single function app - is supported?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a VS 2019 solution, with two functions.  One Durable Function with an Orchestration Client triggered by a BLOB trigger and its related activities.  And another non-durable function triggered by a service bus event trigger.

The non-durable function triggered by a service bus event, creates a blob that triggers the durable function.

I setup a taskhub for the Durable Function.  Deployed both the functions onto Azure on cloud.

For some reason, the functions work fine and get triggered the first time.  The orchestrator does its job.  The second time on, the orchestration client, gets triggered.  But the orchestrator function is not getting triggered.

Looking for the durable function related tables in the storage explorer, I do not see them - they don't seem to be getting created.

Using 1.8.3 version of Durable Task extensions.

Was wondering if I can have both durable and non-durable functions within the same function app?  Was about to try moving them into separate function apps and VS 2017 solutions.

Anyone aware of any such limitations of Durable functions co-existing with non-durable functions within the same function app?

Regards
-Athadu

Answer (score 0):

Realized whey the TaskHub tables were not getting created.

I had the hubName in host.json as

```
      "version": "2.0",
      "extensions": {
          "extensions": {
          "durableTask": {
            "hubName": "%DataLoaderFunctionAppTaskHub%"
          }
        }
      },
```

Changing it to

```
      "version": "2.0",
      "extensions": {

          "durableTask": {
            "hubName": "%DataLoaderFunctionAppTaskHub%"
          }

      },
```

...fixed the issue.

Now, I have a a Durable function co-existing with non-durable functions within the same function app in the same VS 2019 solution working successfully.

Regards
Athadu